# Arithmetic operations using console application

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to create an application to record the time elapsed per machine using simple arithmetic operations.

Using console application, with parameters of number of loop and the threads to use with the code below:

```
public static Int64 IterationCount { get; set; }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int iterations = int.Parse(args[0]);
    int threads = int.Parse(args[1]);

    IterationCount = iterations * 1000000000;

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Calculate());
        Task.WaitAll();
    }   
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed={0}", sw.Elapsed);
}
```

And my `Calculate` method:

```
private static void Calculate()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < IterationCount; i++)
    {
        a = 1 + 2;
        b = 1 - 2;
        c = 1 * 2;
        a = 1 / 2;
    }
}
```

Now I think this is not working because the result of my elapsed time when I entered **10 iterations (I am multiplying the first parameter to 1 billion: 10 * 1,000,000,000)** and **4 threads** is:

```
00:00:00:0119747
```

Any thing I missed?

Comment: You're probably running into a compiler optimization. You are performing arithmetic involving two constants, so I'd suspect that the compiler is automatically performing the arithmetic and storing the result in the compiled code, so in reality all the code is doing is performing 4 simple assignments.

Comment: This might not solve your problem but I guess you should place `Task.WaitAll();` outside thread creation loop. This might be handy later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `Task.WaitAll()` has no effect as the signature of the function is

`public static void WaitAll(params Task[] tasks)`.

You see, you can supply a variable count of `Tasks` to wait for and you call this function with no task; so it will not wait at all.

If you replace your code by the following, you will see the effect.

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[threads];
for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
{
    tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Calculate());
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Comment: By the way: you have to use `Int64` also for your local variable `iterations` as you get an overflow otherwise. You can see that if you check the value of your `IterationCount` variable after assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my comment is accurate. If I copy the contents of your `Calculate` method into Visual Studio:

```
private static void Calculate()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < IterationCount; i++)
    {
        a = 1 + 2;
        b = 1 - 2;
        c = 1 * 2;
        d = 1 / 2;
    }
}
```

after compilation, the generated C# code looks like this:

```
private static void Calculate()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Program.IterationCount; i++)
    {
        Program.a = 3;
        Program.b = -1;
        Program.c = 2;
        Program.d = 0;
    }
}
```

Instead, you're going to have to make one of the constants into a variable:

```
private static void Calculate()
{
    int x = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < IterationCount; i++)
    {
        a = x + 2;
        b = x - 2;
        c = x * 2;
        d = x / 2;
    }
}
```

This code becomes:

```
private static void Calculate()
{
    int x = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < Program.IterationCount; i++)
    {
        Program.a = x + 2;
        Program.b = x - 2;
        Program.c = x * 2;
        Program.d = x / 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It makes a lot of sense because I am never really making arithmetic operations with the code I had.